# Is there a way to setup multiple devices and/or synchronize apps or even manage multiple devices?

Tags: applications, sync, installation

So, imagine you had 100 or more Android devices and you're asked to install 10 specific apps on each of them.

What would be the fastest way to do this?
Is there any way to manage multiple devices at once somehow?

I've seen "[is there a way to automatize the setup/configuration of an android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/167687/is-there-a-way-to-automatize-the-setup-configuration-of-an-android-device)" but it's an old question from 2017 and I wonder whether there is anything out there by now that could make this easier.

I don't even dare to ask whether there exist more sophisticated tools by now which would even allow me to manage devices as an administrator or something like that.

Comment: I think the question is not how can you setup the device but how much are you willing to pay for? There are MDM solutions and special Android devices that can be configured in bulk but that all requires special paid services or devices.

Comment: @Robert I see. What's an MDM solution, though? Could you name me one or two that I can take a look at?

Comment: @Robert Okay, just googled "android mdm solutions". I see. Didn't know that these exist. Thank you. This might already be what I was looking for!